# How can I sort an ArrayList with Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, insertion-sort

I've got an assignment where my teacher is asking us to import a text file with 2043 Euromillions keys with this format:

```
1987 45 12 14 39 43 48 8 10
1981 23 12 18 22 29 45 10 12
1980 6 29 31 45 46 50 4 8
2018 19 2 4 16 19 50 6 12
1986 23 1 10 33 38 42 7 12
1986 40 18 23 26 27 36 7 12
...
```

I've imported the file to an ArrayList and I need to use Insertion Sort to sort the keys by date(first number is year and the next following is week) and with the following format:

```
{1987/45} |12|14|39|43|48| |8|10|
{1981/23} |12|18|22|29|45| |10|12|
...
```

Any ideas on how to sort the keys by date and store them in an Array or ArrayList?

I've imported the file to an ArrayList but idk if it was a good idea, I tried sorting the ArrayList but with no success.

```
private static ArrayList<String> ImportedKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void importarChaves() {

String linha;

        int year,week,ball1,ball2,ball3,ball4,ball5,star1,star2;

        File file=new File("Documento/euromilhoes.txt");
        Scanner leitor=null;
        try {
            leitor = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int count = 0;
        while(leitor.hasNextLine()){

            linha=leitor.nextLine();
            // System.out.println(linha);

            Scanner lerString=new Scanner(linha);

            year=lerString.nextInt();
            week=lerString.nextInt();
            ball1=lerString.nextInt();
            ball2=lerString.nextInt();
            ball3=lerString.nextInt();
            ball4=lerString.nextInt();
            ball5=lerString.nextInt();
            star1=lerString.nextInt();
            star2=lerString.nextInt();

            ImportedKeys.add(linha);

            count++;
            lerString.close();


        }
```

Comment: I can tell that you're a beginning coding student. Congratulations! Try breaking your challenge into manageable pieces and write different functions that handle each part. Additionally, put extra thought to choosing meaningful variables names - it'll make your code much more readable both for you and for others

Comment: This isn't a "code this for me" site, you need to have at least attempted what you need help with. Please read [ask] and for future questions, you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda Never asked anyone to code for me, all I asked was if anyone had an idea on how to sort the ArrayList with the keys inside, isn't it the point of this website helping and getting your questions answered?

Comment: At present, your question contains no code to do with sorting. All you're doing is loading numbers into an ArrayList. This site does not explain algorithms, it mainly helps people debug their code. Since you provided no sorting code to debug, I assumed you wanted someone to "explain" it to you by coding it.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. First, an Insertion Sort is a very specific type of sort where you sort as you're inserting. That is, at any given time, your array is sorted. When you add the 400th element, it is insert into the correct location.

Here's what I would do. First, I'd start with a much shorter sample file so your output is reasonable. 10 lines.

I would create an object that represents one line, but not as a string, but as an object with the various parts. Remember you can't do a string comparison because week 6 will sort after week 11. So your object might contain a numeric year, numeric week, and then whatever the rest of that stuff is.

Then I would do this: I would write JUST an input method that reads the file and produces an (unsorted) array of your new objects. Test it by reading in your file and printing out the results. This will verify you're reading properly.

Then I would understand a few concepts.

1. An empty list is sorted.
2. A list with 1 item is sorted.
3. If a list is sorted, you can do a binary search on it.

What is a binary search?

```
class MyArray extends ArrayList<MyObject> {
    public int insertionPoint(int year, int month {
         return insertionPoint(year, month, 0, length());
    }

    private int insertionPoint(int year, int month, int low, int high) {
        if (low >= high) {
             return low;
        }
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        MyObject obj = get(mid);
        if (obj.year < year || (obj.year == year && obj.month < month)) {
            return insertionPoint(year, month, low, mid);
        }
        return insertionPoint(year, month, mid+1, high);
    }
}
```

This is a binary search. This is a VERY VERY important concept. Your list is sorted, which means you can quickly find an existing object (or where a new object should go) by dividing the list in half. Let's say there are 2000 items. You check the 1000th item. If you are searching for a spot before that (see the if-statement), then. you only have to look in the first half of the list. Otherwise you look in the second half.

Once you have an insertion point, you can simply insert your NEW item into the list at that point. And THAT is an insertion list.

Note: I'm writing the code by hand not in an IDE. It might not be perfect.

All told, when you're done, this SHOULD be fewer than 100 lines of code. That should be enough to define your new object plus define a sorted list that knows how to do an insert, plus the code to test it.

But the trick of an insertion sort:

1. Keep your array sorted as you go
2. Understand a binary search
3. You need to understand recursion. My second method above is highly recursive. It breaks the list down into smaller and smaller pieces until it figures out where your next item should go.

So what you do:

1. Make your MyObject object (or whatever you call it).
2. int location = myList.insertLocation(object.year, object.week)
3. add(location, object)

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Joseph Larson, I'm going to follow your advice for sure and try to solve this problem with your method.